# Matlab detectSURFFeatures() error: "Expected input number 1, I, to be two-dimensional."

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

I'm following Matlab > Help guide "Object Detection in a Cluttered Scene Using Point Feature Matching" and detectSURFFeatures() gets error because it expects a 2-dimensional input argument.   .png doesn't work either.

> > boxImage = imread('C:\WORK\images for feature matching\iPhone6p_back_clean.JPG');
> >
> > boxPoints = detectSURFFeatures(  boxImage );

Error using detectSURFFeatures
Expected input number 1, I, to be two-dimensional.

Error in detectSURFFeatures>checkImage (line 124)
validateattributes(I,{'logical', 'uint8', 'int16', 'uint16', ...

Error in detectSURFFeatures (line 81)
checkImage(I);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the fix:

```
boxPoints = detectSURFFeatures( rgb2gray( boxImage ));
```

Comment: can you please explain why was this happening?

Comment: @AsimRazaKhan, `detectSURFFeatures` only operates on grayscale images. It does not use any color information, so allowing the function to take an RGB image would be misleading.